# How to sort string data that represents numbers

Tags: sql, sorting

My client has a set of numeric data stored in a string field in a database. So of course it doesn't sort correctly. These rows sort like this:

```
105    
3   
44
```

When they should sort like this:

```
3    
44    
105
```

This is very much a legacy database and I can't change it at all. I also can't change the software that uses the database. The client doesn't own it or have the source code. It has never worked the way they want. However, there is an unused string field that I could use to sort on (only a small number of fields can be sorted on.)

What I would like to do is take the input data, derive a string from it, and store the new string in the unused field, such that when the data is sorted on this new data, the original data sorts correctly, i.e., numerically.

So, for an overly simplistic example, if the algorithm produced the following new data:

```
105   -> c
3     -> a
44    -> b
```

Then when the second column was sorted, the first column would look 'correct'.

The tricky bit is that when new rows are added to the database, they must also sort correctly, without having to regenerate the sort data for all rows. This is the part of the problem that has my brain in a twist. I'm not sure it's actually possible.

You can assume that the number will never be more than 5 'digits'.

I realize this is a total kludge, but since I can't change the system, I have to find a work around, rather than a quality solution. Welcome to the real world.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ S O L U T I O N ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I don't think this is an uncommon problem, so here are the results of Gordon's solution:

```
mysql> select * from t order by new;
+------+------------+
| orig | new        |
+------+------------+
| 3    | 0000000003 |
| 44   | 0000000044 |
| 105  | 0000000105 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: Can't you just pad with zeros?

Comment: Why down vote the question? I didn't invent the original database structure, just trying to solve a real-world problem.

Comment: Given that the question is about a database and you are looking for a solution in that environment, I added the sql tag.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, good idea.

Comment: Your proposed solution simply makes the problem worse.

Comment: @John . . . Perhaps the title was drawing downvotes (I don't downvote).  You do not need a new type of sorting algorithm.  You can use any existing algorithm and just change the comparison method.  In any case, because you have an actual problem with a database, it is probably better to look for a solution in that domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can just do:

```
order by cast(col as int)
```

This will convert the string representation to a number and use that for ordering.  There is no need for an additional column.  If you add one, I would recommend adding a numeric column to contain the actual value.

If you really want to store something in the unused field, then you can left pad the number.  How to do this depends on the database, but here is one typical method:

```
update t
    set unused = right(concat('0000000000', col), 10);
```

Not all databases support these two specific functions, but all offer this basic functionality in some method.

Comment: H'mmm... I'm not sure I understand this solution. Let me try it and see what  it produces.

Comment: Ah, okay. I get it. That will do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 ORDER BY LENGTH(column1) ASC, column1 ASC
```

(Adjust the column and table name for your environment.)
This is a bit of a hack but works as long as the "numbers" in your string column are natural, non-negative numbers only.

If you are looking for a more sophisticated approach or algorithm, try searching for [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) together with your DBMS.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can't change any of the software that uses the database. The client doesn't own the software or have source code. I need a work around, not a good solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I guess it boils down to zero-padding the string field and store the zero-padded values in the unused field, if you can sort by that unused field. See Gordon Linoffs answer.